# How to do Validation in the get service method instead of returning entire json Data in angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular

Below is the code of index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularCustomer1</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/popper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js"></script>
</html>
```

Below is the code of app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Below is the code of app.component.html

```
Customer Details
<ng-container *ngFor='let customer Of customers'>
  {{ customer.custmerId }}
  {{ customer.customerName}}
</ng-container>
```

Below is the code app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerService } from './../services/customer.service'
import { Customer } from './../model/Customer'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'angular-customer1';

  customers : Array<Customer> = [];

  constructor( private  customerService: CustomerService ) {  }

  ngOnInit()  {
    this.customers = this.customerService.getCustomers();
  }
}
```

Below is the code of CustomerService Component

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Customer } from './../model/Customer'
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {forEach} from "@angular-devkit/schematics";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerService {

  constructor() { }

  getCustomers()  {

    let customers : Array<Customer> = [];
    // @ts-ignore
    $.ajax({
      url: ' some service url.',
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      type: 'GET',
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      data: {},
      success(data) {
        const parseddata = JSON.parse(data);
        parseddata.forEach( (item) => {
          let address = '';
          let phone = '';
          let email = '';
          if (item.Address === '' || item.Address === undefined || item.Address == null) {
            address += '';
          }
          else {
            address += item.Address + ' ,';
          }
          if (item.City === '' || item.City === undefined || item.City == null) {
            address += '';
          }
          else {
            address += item.City + ' ,';
          }
          if (item.State === '' || item.State === undefined || item.State == null) {
            address += '';
          }
          else {
            address += item.State + ' ,';
          }
          if (item.Country === '' || item.Country === undefined || item.Country == null) {
            address += '';
          }
          else {
            address += item.Country;
          }
          if (item.Zip === '' || item.Zip === undefined || item.Zip == null) {
            address += '';
          }
          else {
            address += item.Zip;
          }

          if (item.Phone1 === '' || item.Phone1 === undefined || item.Phone1 == null) {
            phone = '';
          }
          else {
            phone = item.Phone1;
          }
          if (item.Email === '' || item.Email === undefined || item.Email == null) {
            email = '';
          }
          else {
            email = item.Email;
          }

          const objCustomer = new Customer(item.CustomerId, item.CustomerName, address, phone, email);
          console.log(objCustomer)
          customers.push(objCustomer);
        });
      },
      error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
      }
    });

    return customers;
  }
}
```

Below is the customer object

```
export class Customer {

    customerId: number;
    customerName: string;
    customerAddress: string;
    customerPhone: string;
    customerEmail: string;

    constructor(customerId: number, customerName: string, customerAddress: string, customerPhone: string, customerEmail: string ) {

      this.customerId = customerId;
      this.customerName = customerName;
      this.customerAddress = customerAddress;
      this.customerPhone = customerPhone;
      this.customerEmail = customerEmail;
    }

  }
```

Below is the json data, since i am not able to give the url to mock the data

```
"[{\"CustomerId\":282,\"CustomerName\":\"PRMP\",\"Address\":null,\"Country\":null,\"City\":null,\"State\":null,\"Zip\":null,\"Phone1\":null,\"Phone1Ext\":null,\"Phone2\":null,\"Phone2Ext\":null,\"Fax\":null,\"Email\":null},{\"CustomerId\":284,\"CustomerName\":\"ABCD\",\"Address\":null,\"Country\":\"USA\",\"City\":\"Malvern\",\"State\":\"PA\",\"Zip\":\"19355\",\"Phone1\":\"+1.484.913.2110  \",\"Phone1Ext\":null,\"Phone2\":null,\"Phone2Ext\":null,\"Fax\":null,\"Email\":null},{\"CustomerId\":291,\"CustomerName\":\"GMRUD\",\"Address\":null,\"Country\":null,\"City\":null,\"State\":null,\"Zip\":null,\"Phone1\":null,\"Phone1Ext\":null,\"Phone2\":null,\"Phone2Ext\":null,\"Fax\":null,\"Email\":null}]"
```

Below are my questions, to solve the angular way.
1. This is a working example with ajax call however i would not want to make ajax call, and use  httpclient call and still i am able to manipulate the data and return the object
2. Ajax call needs jquery and i would not want to use it also

Comment: you can shorthand object properties in typescript... your entire customer class could just be:  `export class Customer { constructor(public customerId: number, ... other props ...  public customerEmail: string) {} }` and it would be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your CustomerService to use HttpClient. Inside of HttpClient you can then use the rxjs map operator inside of the pipe to modify your response into the format you desire.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Customer } from './../model/Customer'
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {forEach} from "@angular-devkit/schematics";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getCustomers(): Observable<Customer[]>  {

    return this.httpClient.get<Customer[]>('some service url')
    .pipe(
         catchError(err => throwError(err)),
         map(x => {
             const customers: Customer[] = [];
             x.forEach(customer => {
                 let address = '';
                 let phone = '';
                 let email = '';

                 address += customer.Address ? `${customer.Address} ,` : '';
                 address += customer.City ? `{${customer.City} ,` : '';
                 address += customer.State ? `${customer.State} ,` : '';
                 address += customer.Country ? `${customer.Country} ,` : '';
                 address += customer.Zip ? `${customer.Zip} ,` : '';

                 phone = customer.Phone1 ? customer.Phone1 : '';

                 email = customer.Email ? customer.Email : '';

                 const objCustomer = new Customer(
                     customer.CustomerId,
                     customer.CustomerName,
                     address,
                     phone,
                     email
                 );

                 console.log(objCustomer);
                 customers.push(objCustomer);
             });

             return customers;
         })
    );
```

}
    }

The component file will also need to be modified to use the new return type of the function. Instead of resolving the observable inside the component since the value in the observable is used only in the template the observable can be resolved there using an async pipe. That allows Angular to handle the subscribing and unsubscribing of the observable for us.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerService } from './../services/customer.service'
import { Customer } from './../model/Customer'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'angular-customer1';

  customers$ : Observable<Array<Customer>> = [];

  constructor( private  customerService: CustomerService ) {  }

  ngOnInit()  {
    this.customers$ = this.customerService.getCustomers();
  }
}
```

Now the *ngFor in the template needs to be modified to consume the customers$ (I like to name my observables, subjects, etc with a trailing $ for quick reference) observable in the template.

```
Customer Details
<ng-container *ngFor='let customer of customers$ | async'>
  {{ customer.custmerId }}
  {{ customer.customerName}}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212529/discussion-on-answer-by-tuckerjt07-how-to-do-validation-in-the-get-service-metho).

Comment: I solved the service layer issue by updating the following return this.httpClient.get<any[]>(' some url here') . Though i was unable to check because of another issue however i would have return type to be customer instead of any. Please advise

Comment: Sure, I'll update the answer, give me a little bit.